# Typescript infer "keys of parent" as type

Tags: typescript, type-inference

How can I infer the keys of the parent as type of a nested property?

```typescript
interface List {
    [key:string]: Definition<keyof List>
}

interface Definition<T> {
    [key:string]: Field<T>
}

type Field<T> = FieldA | FieldB<T>;

interface FieldA {
    type: string
}

interface FieldB<T> {
    definition: T 
}

const list:List = {
    def1: {
        field1: {
            type: 'a'
        }
    },
    def2: {
        definition: 'def1'
                    // ~~~ Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'Field<never>'.
    }

}
```

Here the type of the `definition` property is `never`. I would like to be `def1 | def2`.

Or more in general to get the keys of the parent object and use it as type.

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=29&ssc=2&pln=1&pc=1#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgDLAM5mQbwFACQA2gNYQCeAXFlKAOYC6lyAIhDKMGMAPYgA8ZcjxhpMYAHx4AvnjyhIsRCjYcQXXgIAqE3IVIVqYWiEbMAYsAgAbACb8dMuWHIAHFJZv2dyALzJPOwBBZAAfAKs7ACEHCQBuOQVoeCQIrxD8Ahd3Zhp6J3lwZOU06Ni9Alt2Tm4+Zi1kAoQ+LGRrcUp0Vv9MqpgARmZMgg4vQYqCLLcIZgByOFnCAlllgBpCPoAmIaW+ms05vv7F5blpIA)

### Simpler version

```typescript
interface List {
    [key:string]:keyof List
}

const list:List = {
    def1: 'def2',
          // ~~~ Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'never'.
    def2: 'def1'
          // ~~~ Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'never'.
}
```

Why `keyof List` is of type `never`? And how can I get the keys considering I don't know them in advance.

Comment: is there a reason not to define keys such as `type TKey = 'def1' | 'def2';` ? is `key` going to be dynamic?

Comment: yes, the keys are dynamic, I don't know in advance what they will be.

Comment: Then you shouldn't expect the compiler to infer a proper type either.

Comment: So it is not possible?

Comment: AFAIK, typescript can't do anything with the * types * generated at runtime (i don't know if its possible either). All the types should be declared at the compile time in order to use type safety.

Comment: You can use `keyof this` to get the fields that Typescript understands even if you don't define them all yourself, but I couldn't figure out a way to get that to apply to your use-case because using that within an indexed type results in TS-breaking recursion.

Comment: I am pretty sure you cannot use `this`. Do you have a playground link?

Answer (score 1):

This works, although it's ugly ;)

```
type List<K extends keyof any> = { [key in K]: K };

const list = new class C implements List<keyof C> {
    def1: 'def2'
    def2: 'def1'
    def5: 'def5'
}
```

That's a bit less ugly and also works ;)

```
type List<T extends object> = { [key in keyof T]: keyof T }
const List = <O extends object>(o: List<O>): List<O> => o;

const list = List({
    def1: 'def2',
    def2: 'def1',
    def5: 'def5'
});
```